# Laravel 4: Unable to generate a URL, as such route does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, twig, laravel-routing

Here is my routes.php:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'mine'], function () {
    Route::get('/first', ['as' => 'mine.first', 'uses' => 'MyApp\Controllers\MyController@first']);
});
```

Here is my HTML/Twig file:

```
{{ form_open({'action': 'mine.first'}) }}
{{ form_submit('Start') }}
{{ form_close }}
```

And here is my controller:

```
class MyController extends BaseController {
    public function first()
    {
        \View::make('stuff.mine.first'); //in folder app/views/stuff/mine
    }
}
```

The error is "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "MyController@first" as such route does not exist.") in "stuff.show" at line 130."

All the answers on this topic that I've seen are to name the route, but I've already done that.

Also, when I go to the URL manually (localhost/mine/first), the screen is blank even though there is HTML in that file.

Any idea what's going on? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mine.first` is a route name, not an action.

Use:

```
{{ form_open({'route': 'mine.first'}) }}
```

As for the view, controller action need to return a Response (the View generates one), so you just need add the proper keyword:

```
  public function first()
  {
     return \View::make('stuff.mine.first');
  }
```